# change CSS for iFrame content inside div element

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to change css for iFrame content inside of a div element using jquery. But I cannot set the class with new css. Here is my HTML and angularjs code.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:0px !important;">
   <div class="portlet box">
    <iframe id="{{Identifier}}" ng-src="{{Url}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

angularjs code

```
$scope.changeContent = function () {
            $("iframe").contents().find('.container').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                margin: "auto"
            });
        }
```

I am using container here as when my HTML is generated inside iframe I would want to change the css for the container dynamically. I am unable to get using above code. Can someone help me with right and better way of doing this ?

Comment: is iframe on same domain as page? When are you calling `changeContent()`?

Comment: It is not on same domain. I would like to call and change css when the content in the iframe is loaded. If it is in same domain, can we manage to change the css ?

Comment: You cannot directly alter content in an iframe if it does not originate from the same origin as the parent page.  The [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  However, if you have source control over both pages, then you can craft yourpages in a special way in order to use a technique called [Web Messaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Messaging) to get around cross-domain issues.  A good library is [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/).

Comment: also if you control both domains you can set `document.domain` the same in both pages